# unable to backup our sharepoint content database "Backup Database is terminating abnormally"

Tags: 2013, sql-server, backup, content-database, database

I want to backup our live Content Database, now i went to "Central aministration>>Backup>>perform backup",, but i could it find our content database. so i try running the following command on the SharePoint server , to backup our content database (which is on another server):-

```
Backup-SPFarm -Directory  c:\f  -BackupMethod Full -Item WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8  -Verbose
```

but i start receiving errors, as shown below:-

[image]

here is part of the backup report showing the exceptions i received:-

```
        [15/02/2016 13:22:28] Verbose: Using directory: c:\f\spbr0000\.
        [15/02/2016 13:22:28] Verbose: The backup/restore process included the following objects:
    ****
                            *******
        [15/02/2016 13:22:28] Backup/Restore Settings:
            Backup
            Backup Method: Full
            Top Component: WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8
            Directory: c:\f
            Configuration only: False
            Progress updated: 5
        [15/02/2016 13:22:28]   Backup threads created: 3
        
        [15/02/2016 13:22:28] Verbose: Adding WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8 to Backup list.
        [15/02/2016 13:22:28] Verbose: Starting OnPrepareBackup event.
        [15/02/2016 13:22:28] Verbose: Starting object: Farm.
        [15/02/2016 13:22:28] Verbose: Saving SPPersistedObject State
        [15/02/2016 13:22:28] Verbose: Starting object: SharePoint_Config.
        [15/02/2016 13:22:28] Verbose: Saving SPPersistedObject State
        [15/02/2016 13:22:28] Verbose: Starting object: Solutions.
        [15/02/2016 13:22:28] Verbose: Starting object: kaboodle.core.wsp.
        [15/02/2016 13:22:28] Verbose: Saving SPPersistedObject State
        [15/02/2016 13:22:28] Verbose: Starting object: 0.
        [15/02/2016 13:22:28] Verbose: Saving SPPersistedObject State
        [15/02/2016 13:22:28] Verbose: Starting object: 
//logs goes here
[WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL Server Connection String: Data Source=TGVSQL02\SPS;Initial Catalog=WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15.
        [15/02/2016 13:22:35] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL Server Command: 
        USE [master]
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name=@db_name)
        BEGIN
             SELECT sum(convert(float,size)) * (8192.0) from [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8].dbo.sysfiles
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT 0
        END
        [15/02/2016 13:22:35] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL Server Connection String: Data Source=TGVSQL02\SPS;Initial Catalog=WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15.
        [15/02/2016 13:22:35] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL command started at: 15/02/2016 13:22:35. This command may take a while to complete and without notification.
        [15/02/2016 13:22:35] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL Server Command: BACKUP DATABASE [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] TO DISK=@db_loc WITH NAME=@db_name, STATS=5, NOINIT, NOSKIP, NOFORMAT, NOREWIND 
            @db_name=WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8, @db_loc=c:\f\spbr0000\000000BC.bak
        [15/02/2016 13:22:35] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL command timeout is set to 1.00 hours.
        [15/02/2016 13:22:35] Warning: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] Cannot open backup device 'c:\f\spbr0000\000000BC.bak'. Operating system error 3(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15100).
        BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
        [15/02/2016 13:22:35] Debug: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
           at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Backup.SPSqlBackupRestoreHelper.RunCommand(SqlCommand sqlCommand, SPBackupRestoreInformation args, Boolean throwOnRestart, Boolean& restart, SPSqlBackupRestoreConnection connection)
        [15/02/2016 13:22:35] Warning: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL command failed and needs to be restarted. The command will be re-started a total of three times before throwing an exception.
        [15/02/2016 13:22:50] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] Retrying to connect to SQL.
        [15/02/2016 13:22:50] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL command started at: 15/02/2016 13:22:50. This command may take a while to complete and without notification.
        [15/02/2016 13:22:50] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL Server Command: BACKUP DATABASE [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] TO DISK=@db_loc WITH NAME=@db_name, STATS=5, NOINIT, NOSKIP, NOFORMAT, NOREWIND 
            @db_name=WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8, @db_loc=c:\f\spbr0000\000000BC.bak
        [15/02/2016 13:22:50] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL command timeout is set to 1.00 hours.
        [15/02/2016 13:22:50] Warning: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] Cannot open backup device 'c:\f\spbr0000\000000BC.bak'. Operating system error 3(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
        BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
        [15/02/2016 13:22:50] Debug: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
           at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Backup.SPSqlBackupRestoreHelper.RunCommand(SqlCommand sqlCommand, SPBackupRestoreInformation args, Boolean throwOnRestart, Boolean& restart, SPSqlBackupRestoreConnection connection)
        [15/02/2016 13:22:50] Warning: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL command failed and needs to be restarted. The command will be re-started a total of three times before throwing an exception.
        [15/02/2016 13:23:50] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] Retrying to connect to SQL.
        [15/02/2016 13:23:50] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL command started at: 15/02/2016 13:23:50. This command may take a while to complete and without notification.
        [15/02/2016 13:23:50] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL Server Command: BACKUP DATABASE [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] TO DISK=@db_loc WITH NAME=@db_name, STATS=5, NOINIT, NOSKIP, NOFORMAT, NOREWIND 
            @db_name=WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8, @db_loc=c:\f\spbr0000\000000BC.bak
        [15/02/2016 13:23:50] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL command timeout is set to 1.00 hours.
        [15/02/2016 13:23:50] Warning: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] Cannot open backup device 'c:\f\spbr0000\000000BC.bak'. Operating system error 3(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
        BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
        [15/02/2016 13:23:50] Debug: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
           at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Backup.SPSqlBackupRestoreHelper.RunCommand(SqlCommand sqlCommand, SPBackupRestoreInformation args, Boolean throwOnRestart, Boolean& restart, SPSqlBackupRestoreConnection connection)
        [15/02/2016 13:23:50] Warning: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL command failed and needs to be restarted. The command will be re-started a total of three times before throwing an exception.
        [15/02/2016 13:26:05] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] Retrying to connect to SQL.
        [15/02/2016 13:26:05] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL command started at: 15/02/2016 13:26:05. This command may take a while to complete and without notification.
        [15/02/2016 13:26:05] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL Server Command: BACKUP DATABASE [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] TO DISK=@db_loc WITH NAME=@db_name, STATS=5, NOINIT, NOSKIP, NOFORMAT, NOREWIND 
            @db_name=WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8, @db_loc=c:\f\spbr0000\000000BC.bak
        [15/02/2016 13:26:05] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL command timeout is set to 1.00 hours.
        [15/02/2016 13:26:06] FatalError: Object WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8 failed in event OnBackup. For more information, see the spbackup.log or sprestore.log file located in the backup directory.
            SqlException: Cannot open backup device 'c:\f\spbr0000\000000BC.bak'. Operating system error 3(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
        BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
        [15/02/2016 13:26:06] Debug:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
           at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Backup.SPSqlBackupRestoreHelper.RunCommand(SqlCommand sqlCommand, SPBackupRestoreInformation args, Boolean throwOnRestart, Boolean& restart, SPSqlBackupRestoreConnection connection)
           at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Backup.SPSqlBackupRestoreHelper.Run(SPBackupRestoreInformation args)
           at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Backup.SPSqlBackupHelper.Run(SPBackupRestoreInformation args)
           at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDatabase.OnBackup(Object sender, SPBackupInformation info)
        [15/02/2016 13:26:06] Verbose: Starting OnBackupComplete event.
        [15/02/2016 13:26:06] Finish Time: 15/02/2016 13:26:06.
        [15/02/2016 13:26:06] Progress: Completed with errors and warnings, please refer to the log file for details.
        [15/02/2016 13:26:06] Verbose: Deleting the file c:\f\spbr0000\spbackup.xml and replacing it.
        [15/02/2016 13:26:06] Verbose: The backup/restore process included the following objects:
        [15/02/2016 13:26:06]     *Farm\
    *****
        
        [15/02/2016 13:26:06] Finished with 6 warnings.
        [15/02/2016 13:26:07] Finished with 1 errors.
        [15/02/2016 13:26:07] FatalError: Backup failed for Object WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8 failed in event OnBackup. For more information, see the spbackup.log or sprestore.log file located in the backup directory.
        [15/02/2016 13:26:07] -------------------------------------------------
```

although each day we perform a full farm backup without any problem,, so not sure why the database backup did not succeed ?

Second question, could these exceptions caused any problem on our database ? i think it should not but just want to make sure? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error tells me that your service account does not have permission on the Backup folder.
Make sure

- Service account under which you running the backup have read/write permission on the folder.
- SQL server Service account should have permission on that folder.

I would always use the UNC path rather local folder.

Comment: i used the UNC path and the backup worked well, but not sure if the original failed backup could have caused any harm to the database, or failed backup should not have any negative effect on the database ?

Comment: So that is the problem, as i mentioned Use the UNC path....fail job dont have any effect on the database normally....if job failed then fine, but if it is running / pausing then it can lock the databases.

Answer (score 1):

Check if there are no space left for Logs to be stored. Also see if there is any update required to Sql Management. I am not sure..but check for starter.

Comment: as i said at the end of each daywe do a full farm backup without any problem,,, not sure what do you mean by space for logs to be stored ? and sql management update ? i mean how these can be related to my problem ?

Comment: ok..forget it...tell me what error you are getting in Event Viewer?

Comment: i will check the event viewer ,, but can you adivce if a  failed backup job can affects the database? as i performed this on a live server,, so not sure if it could cause problems i need to should check ? or backup db could not in any way cause problems, as it will only try to retrieve data..

Comment: No a failed backup shouldn't affect the database.

Comment: now i changed the directory inside the powershell command from "c:\f" to be the global name such as "\\servername\f" and the backup worked well..

Comment: Thats write..to add anything in C:// drive..u need to have Admin rights.. u wont be able to do with any other accounts.. or else make a folder inside C drive and give the path of that folder.